# how to find minimum required Sequence Lenght for enough valid numbers (efficiently)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, sequence

I have a timeseries dataframe with multiple columns, which contain NaNs independently from each other.

And I have a given lenght "LEN" every sequence of **valid** elements should **at least** have.
(By "sequence I mean collecting the values in the indices before.)

Iterating is extremly time inefficient, but it would look similar to this:

```
LEN = 100
maximum_sequence_len = 0  

for i in range(len(df)):      # for every index
    for col in df.columns:    # for every column
        
        df_ = df[col].iloc[:i].dropna()
         
        seq_end_ix   = i
        seq_start_ix = get_seq_start_where_every_col_has_enough_valids(
                                                df,seq_end,LEN)
        
        necessary_len = len( df.loc[seq_start_ix:seq_end_ix] ) 
        
        if maximum_sequence_len < necessary_len :
            maximum_sequence_len = necessary_len

get_seq_start_where_every_col_has_enough_valids(df,seq_end_ix,LEN)
    # determine the index where every column contains at least "LEN" valid elements

    first_SEQ_LEN_Sample_start_ix = start_ix
    
    for col in df.columns:   
        col_df = df[col].dropna() 

        temp = col_df[col_df.index <= seq_end_ix ].index[-(LEN)] 

        if temp < first_SEQ_LEN_Sample_start_ix: 
            first_SEQ_LEN_Sample_start_ix = temp    
            
    seq_start_ix = first_SEQ_LEN_Sample_start_ix  
     
    return seq_start_ix
```

An Example:

```
LEN = 6 # in this example we have to have at least 6 valid elements in the frame of rows before

print(df)
>>>>
              A          B          C          D          E          F
index          
0            1          1          1          1          1          1
1            1          1          1          1          1          1
2            1          1          1          1          1 |        1
3          NaN          1          1        NaN          1 |        1
4          NaN          1          1        NaN          1 |        1
5            1          1          1          1          1 |        1
6            1          1          1          1        NaN |        1
7          NaN          1          1        NaN          1 |        1
8          NaN          1          1          1          1 |        1
9            1          1          1          1        NaN |        1
10           1          1          1          1        NaN |        1
11           1          1          1        NaN        NaN |        1
12           1          1          1          1        NaN |        1
13           1          1          1          1        NaN |        1
14           1        NaN          1          1        NaN |*       1
16           1          1          1          1          1        NaN
17         NaN          1          1          1          1          1
18         NaN          1          1          1          1        NaN
19           1          1          1          1          1          1

# ==> Result: 13
# *here, longest sequence necessary to get minimum 6 valids in EVERY column has a length of 13. note, that if the other columns contained more NaNs in the marked indices, then it would probably have taken more than 13.
```

The problem is that I want to create sequence samples, but dont know how long they have to be so that each sample has at least "LEN" valid elements in every column.

Comment: Are you able to `df.dropna`?

Comment: nope. the if we drop the NaNs, the values in the same rows will be dropped too :( @inspectorG4dget

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to maintain a vector counter with one counter for each column.

The vector counter should signal a 'window-ready' if all counters are at least 6. If a window (start_index, end_index) is ready, you can emit all rows in the window and reset the window's start_index, end_index to current row and reset all counters to zero.

Repeat until end of data.

```
Algorithm get_windows(data[][])
  counters: array of integers of length = data.cols, values initialized to 0
Begin
  window_start_index = 0
  window_end_index = 0

  for each row in data
    for each col in row
      if(value(col) != NaN)
        counters[index(col)]++;
      end if
    next // col

    // check if row causes window to continue
    continue_flag = false;
    for each counter in counters
      if(counter != 6)
        continue_flag = true
        exit for loop
      end if
    next // counter
    
    if(continue_flag)
      window_end_index++;
    else
      // we have a window (window_start_index, window_end_index)
      // both inclusive

      // do something with the window

      // reset counters
      for each counter in counters
         counter = 0
      next

    end if

  next // row

End Algorithm
```

Is this single pass algorithm what you need?

Comment: how efficient is this on a df with about 0.5-1mio rows and 50 columns?

Comment: You are doing a single pass over the data. So, it is O(n) algorithmic complexity. You can't get better than O(n) for an algorithm that has to look at all n items!

Comment: @wgiri iterating over a df might be slow, is there a way to 'convert' this in a numpy matrice

Comment: The algorithm pseudocode I have mentioned above can be used on a 2D array as well.